# What are the different export file size limits in SPD 2007?

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, migration, export

I am trying to migrate some document libraries and lists using SPD from one site collection to another. (I have well researched this and am very aware that the best method is a console app)
I stumbled upon the export features in Sharepoint designer but couldn't find file size limits.
[Sharepoint designer 2007 export or import a web package](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/export-or-import-a-web-package-HA010081923.aspx)

I was trying to use either a personal web package or a .cmp file but as the lists get bigger errors appear. The only thing I am adding to the package is the doc library I want to export.

> Web Package "L:\My Web Package.fwp" creation failed. This could be due to network problems or other external changes to the source web site.

(Also, I am running SPD as a remote app and for some reason my export->file menu item is grayed out. If know why this happens as well please let me know.)

Update: The file menu item being grayed out was due to a administrative restriction on the remote app server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to my understanding moss 07 is capped by default at 50mb but could be wrong (thats the last time I checked)! So on that basis I would also have to presume SPD would also be capped at 50mb....

You are right tho it does get a bit messy when you get to bigger file sizes especialy over 50mb as its prone to time out.

Have you looked into making a site template instead? It works better.

as for the grayed out i have no idea tbh.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/back-up-restore-or-move-a-sharepoint-site-HA010069939.aspx

**EDIT**

For refrence you can increase the list template like so:

> stsadm -o setproperty -propertyname max-template-document-size
>   -propertyvalue 50000000

as an example you would do it like this:

```
STSADM –o setproperty –pn max-template-document-size –pv 524288000
```

> The –pv value is the value in Bytes this is the value you wish to set the limit
>   to. The maximum value that can be set is 500 MB or 524288000 Bytes.
>
> STSADM will work hard at this command for a while. Just be
>   patient and do NOT terminate STSADM midstream!

http://sarpoint.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/increasing-the-maximum-size-of-list-templates/

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Sounds like thats probably right. I wonder if increasing the max size for list template using the STSADM command would fix this? I'm not going to try it because its too risky but just wanted to add that on for anyone else that may have the same problem.

Comment: iv changed my answer to add the increase of list template for you if you do wish to go down that route :) or for anyone else that comes accross this!